# Dealing with incomplete data using NSURLSessionDataTask

Tags: ios, macos, nsurlsession, nsurlsessiondownloadtask

I'm using `NSURLSessionDataTask` to download data. I'm seeing cases in which the connection is interrupted and yet I still receive data. How should I deal with these cases?

- Am I guarranted to get an error of some kind?
- Should I compare the data length with the response `expectedContentLength`? Is it reliable? What if it's not available?
- Something else?

Code:

```
NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sharedSession];
NSURLSessionDataTask *task = [session dataTaskWithURL:url completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error)
{
    if (error)
    {
        NSLog(@"Request %@ failed with error %@", url, error);
        return;
    }
    const long long expectedContentLength = response.expectedContentLength;
    if (expectedContentLength > -1)
    {
        const NSUInteger dataLength = data.length;
        if (dataLength < expectedContentLength)
        {
            NSLog(@"Request %@ received %ld out of %ld bytes", url, (long)dataLength, (long)expectedContentLength);
            return;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        // How do I know if data is complete?
    }
}];
[task resume];
```

Comment: SAME PROBLEM HERE. I download an image, the NSURLSessionDataTask state goes to complete but the image data is incomplete. Did you ever find any info on this?

Comment: The code I posted seems to handle most cases, assuming your server returns the proper content length.

Comment: I wonder of this is the best solution, do you happen to still have any links to  docs teaching how to handle this?